# Find and replace single word in string using QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, find

How do I find and replace a single word of a string?

e.g.
Calle Iparraguirre to Iparraguirre

I've tried:

```
replace( 'Calle\\s', 'Calle\\s', '')

replace( "name",'calle','')
```

and all combinations of code, but nothing is working :/

*I've read other Q&A's but no result

Comment: I am not familiar with QGis field calculator but if you can put a python script in there like ArcMap, you could use python's STR.replace(findSTR, replaceSTR): see here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the function help, the correct syntax is

```
replace('QGIS SHOULD ROCK','SHOULD','DOES') → 'QGIS DOES ROCK'
```

Note that the function is case senstive so Calle != calle

Comment: I think i've put in the right syntax, but it removes all "name" strings (i checked Update existing fields: name)  replace( 'Calle ' , 'Calle ' , '')

Comment: Well, you are replacing 'Calle ' in 'Calle ' with an empty string ... therefore the result is empty ... Use replace(name, 'Calle ', '') instead.